# Devise: In all pages, redirect non-signed-in users to homepage

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have set up Devise in a from-scratch new Rails3 application, and signup/signin/signout works fine.

Now, what is the standard way to make sure pages can only be viewed by people who are signed in?

Non-signed in people would be redirected to the homepage (except when they are on the signup page, of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution! I just need to add this as the second line in each controller:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

For instance:

```
class MonkeysController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

If you know any better solution, feel free to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting it in each controller, couldn't you just put it in ApplicationController?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
end
```

I put that in my application controller and now when I navigate to any page in my application, it redirects me to new_user_session_path or "users/sign_in."